# Resources distribution to IIS processes and standard windows applications

Tags: windows, iis, resources

We have a server machine with very good configuration on our LAN

- 4 GB of RAM
- 1 TB HDD
- Quad Processor

We can have 2 types of application running on the server

1. ASP.NET web application running under the IIS supervision
2. Standard windows application running with administraive account.

My question is how the resources are distributed between these apps. I know the windows application can utilize high resources (100% CPU, 100% RAM etc.), but I am not sure how much access does the asp.net processes does have on these resources. It is limited for them or same like the windows application? Also if there is any limitation then how can we control this.

The reason I am asking this question is from our web application we want to execute some heavy operation. What are best way to do that. Should I go for a windows services, MSMQ, or can use asp.net account?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this [Microsoft article](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/8dbb74b9-b8ed-430b-bbc0-4ba70bcf9ff5.mspx?mfr=true) - You can also set the affinity on processes in the task manager to restrict processes to a certain number of cores.